# WP_User_Query order by registered

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the list of a specific user type and order them by their registration date.

I searched for ways to do it from here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters to several Stackoverflow posts but nothing worked so far.

Could you check my code and tell me what's wrong?

```
$args_tilisateur = array(
'role' => 'coureur',
    'orderby ' => 'registered',
    'order' => 'ASC'
```

);
$usi = new WP_User_Query( $args_tilisateur );

Then to display I do :

```
if ( !empty($usi->results) ) {
foreach ( $usi->results as $ut ):
    $user_id = $ut->ID;
    $user_info = get_userdata((int)$user_id);
```

And so on with echoing the values from $user_info.

Comment: try "user_registered"

Comment: My bad it was because of the space after orderby ...

Comment: Yeah remove that.

Comment: thanks for you fast comment though :)

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it was only because of the extra space after orderby in the array :

```
$args_tilisateur = array(
'role' => 'coureur',
'orderby' => 'registered',
'order' => 'ASC');
```